# I need to re route action based on some criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If a user is logged in and the ChangePasswordRequired flag is set, i need to disregard the current action and redirect them to the ChangePassword action.

In other words, I do not want the user to be able to do anything until he or she changes his or her password.

Which method should my base controller override and how should I handle the redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create your own action filter.

The exact type of action filter you want to use is one that implements `IAuthorizationFilter` and the method you want to use it the `OnAuthorizing()` or close. This filter type is executed before all the others.

Instead of the `[Authorize]` filter you would use your own filter. Be sure to make your flag check **and** whether the user is authenticated (`Request.IsAuthenticated`)

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: if i go this route do i have to decorate every actionresult method with my filter attribute or can i just decorate my base controller with it?
What would be the difference with what you suggested and with overriding the OnActionExecuting and changing the ActionResult there?

Comment: You can set it in The Global.asax. GlobalConfiguration class

Comment: Sorry thats for web API, you should use the GlobalFilters class

Answer (score 1):

I would use an actionfilter that you add to every controller class that should implement this behaviour. You can read some more on at this [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/14/aspnetmvc-filters.aspx) by Phil Haack